# Why 'undefined' after fetch via Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I've made a simple experiment to understand fetch on a model and fetch on a collection. However, this code gives 'undefined' for both:

```
    // Model and Collection
    var SingleItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
      urlRoot : '/data/item.json',
      parse: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          return response;
      }
    });

    var ManyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: SingleItem,
      url: '/data/items.json',
    });

    var many = new ManyCollection();
    many.fetch();
    console.log(many);

    var single = new SingleItem();
    single.fetch({
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("OK"); 
        console.log(data.toJSON());
      },
      error: function(data){
        console.log("NOK");
      }
    });


    console.log(single.get('name'));
```

The demo is also here: https://github.com/mulderp/backbone-model-fetch

Why do I get 'undefined'? What am I missing?

(output from dev console:

[image: dev output]

Comment: Surely you need to put your `get` logging inside the `success` callback? `fetch` is asynchronous remember.

Comment: yes, there was my blind spot... thanks! it's the answer to this question. maybe you want to put it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch` is asynchronous: it will return immediately, before the data has been fetched.

Moving the debug logic to inside the `success` handlers should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem too. But could you please tell me how you knew `fetch` takes an object with config? Because I could not find any reference to that in Backbone's [documentation](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Model-fetch)

Comment: In the documentation you link to, it's defined as `fetch([options])`, indicating it takes an options options argument. It then goes on to say "Accepts success and error callbacks in the options hash". It's a common Backbone idiom - many methods take an options object. If in doubt, you can always read the annotated source: http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-55